# Leaflet.markercluster: Animation is not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Using [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/tree/leaflet-0.7) one can see a nice animation in their [example](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html). With animation enabled such as:

```
L.markerClusterGroup({
  animate: true,
  animateAddingMarkers: true
});
```

The [L.DomUtil.TRANSITION](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domutil-transition%0A%09%09) has this value: **webkitTransition**

I still don't see any animations. Is it the problem that I am using AngujarJS or is it something else?

Comment: Many other projects are using leaflet-angular-directive with clustered groups. Would you be able to reproduce your issue on Plunker, so that people can pinpoint what could be wrong in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was missing the css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css">
```